# How is the smooth Dice coefficient is differentiable but not the smooth IoU?

Tags: image-segmentation, loss-function, calculus, semantic-segmentation, differentiation

I would like to know how the smooth Dice coefficient is differentiable but not a smooth IoU. Exactly which part of smooth IoU makes is non-differentiable, since the equation for two seems quite similar. Calculus or differentiation isn't my strong suit, so I would appreciate if someone could explain or point me to a helpful resource.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?